# how do you swap two arrays in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swap

Is this a convenient way for swapping two ivar arrays in objective C?

```
- (void) foo {
    NSArray *aux;
    aux = array1;
    array2 = array1;
    array1 = array2;
}
```

Are there any alternatives? May it have problems related to retainCount under some circumstances?
I am confused because in the program that I am reviewing the swap is done by:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSArray *aux;
    aux = array1;
    [aux retain];
    array2 = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    [aux release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you're swapping just the pointers. And by the way, you're doing
it wrong:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSArray *aux;
    aux = array1;       /* aux is array1 */
    array2 = array1;    /* array2 is array1 */
    array1 = array2;    /* array1 is array1 */
}
```

If you have properties on those arrays, I'd recommend going with it:

```
- (void)swapMyArrays
{
    NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.array1];
    [self setArray2:array1];
    [self setArray1:temp];
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend it for any kind of property (retain, assign or copy)?

Comment: Retain and copy are fine. Using it with an assign property will just swap the pointers for array2 and break array1, since it was assigned to an autoreleased object in my example. Anyway, it's not very common to use an assign property in objects.

Comment: I think there is also a typo in your code (in SwapArrays first statement).

Comment: Sorry user870560, I'm not in my computer with a compiler right now, and I can't spot it. What might be the error?

Comment: I think it should be like this: NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.array2]; Anyway thank you for the answer, it helped me to clarify things.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them will work, you are not using your aux variable anywhere, at the end they will both point to the same memory location do this instead:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSArray *aux;
    aux = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    array2 = aux;
}
```

Comment: This will have issues if array1 or array2 are synthesized, no?

Comment: Well it depends if you want to retain the value assigned then you need to call retain, if it is synthesized it will depend on how it was declared, although unless you are using self.array1 you are not assigning using the setter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake at the end, and it should be:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSArray *aux;
    aux = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    array2 = aux; // instead of array2 = array1
}
```

otherwise you make both arrays the same one.

I edited the answer as for the (correct) comments regarding a mistake in the variables I made.

Comment: this is incorrect, in your example both will end up pointing to the memory location array1 had.

Comment: This will have issues if array1 or array2 are synthesized, no?

Comment: @Oscar Gomez - That was a typo, thanks for  pointing that out.